# Date.now() returns wrong date

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, date

I have this mongoose schema

```
const postSchema= new Schema({
body:{ type: String, required:true, validate:bodyValidators},
createdBy: { type: String},
to: {type:String, default:null },
createdAt: { type:Date, default:Date.now()},
likes: { type:Number,default:0},
likedBy: { type:Array},
dislikes: { type:Number, default:0},
dislikedBy: { type:Array},
comments: [
    {
        comment: { type: String, validate: commentValidators},
        commentator: { type: String}
    }
]
```

});

every posts on my app is returns Aug 20, 2017 at 10:01 PM but where i am it's 2 hours more.
here's the HTML, i'm using Angular4.

```
{{post.createdAt | date: 'MMM dd, yyyy'}} at {{post.createdAt | date:'shortTime'}}
```

I just can't understand why

Comment: `Date.now()` with parentheses in this case gets converted to a date when you start your application. Did you start your server 2 hours ago?

Comment: i sure did ... that's logic but i don't understand why it used to work lately

Comment: If you use parentheses there, it's only going to be executed once, on application start. I've not tried it, but this might help: http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/node.js/12669615.html

Comment: thanks for your answer all i had to do is set it up in the front-end

Comment: [`Date.now()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.now) doesn't return a date, it returns a time value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose is receiving the value calculate at the time you start it, instead of the function. You should pass it the function instead of running it. Whenever you use parenthesis you are executing the function instead of referencing it. I had the same problem once.

Answer (score 1):

In **mongoose** you can do like following. Using **update()** or **findOneAndUpdate()**

with **{upsert: true}** option

you can use **$setOnInsert** without having to pass them in everytime new MyModel() is called.

```
var update = {
  updatedAt: new Date(),
  $setOnInsert: {
     createdAt: new Date()
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the value in the wrong way. try this:

```
createdAt: { 
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now 
}
```

Read this link for further understanding:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html